# Facebook graph api to send app request to friends from iPhone app

Tags: iphone

i require to send app request to friends in my facebook profile. So can any one suggest me graph api available to achieve this, i prefer graph because i have been using the graph api for all other tasks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one you will get all your friends list which is there in your facebook.

```
-(IBAction)getMeFriendsButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:nil];
    NSLog(@"getMeFriendsButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
}
```